# Time limit exceeded while enabling all Apex classes in permission set

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, workbench

I have created a permission set.

The permission set does not have access to any apex class:

[image]

Enabling all classes in the permission set:

[image]

Getting the below error:

[image]

I can enable the permissions for classes by enabling those in patches or retrieving the metadata file and enable the classes in the file then deploy.

I followed [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331630&type=1&mode=1) link, to insert record using **Workbench** to enable access.

But the CSV is not getting inserted successfully:

[image]

What is the quickest way to enable all Apex classes in the permission sets?

Comment: What is the error in case of bulk api insert?

Comment: in general, only the apex classes that are invocable, rest, webservices, ... need to enabled to users so this requirement is overkill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got class names using SOQL.

```
SELECT Name FROM ApexClass
```

Using workbench:

[image]

Put those classes in the below structure:

```
<classAccesses>
    <apexClass>ClassName</apexClass>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
</classAccesses>
```

And deployed using meta-data.

Though this is not what I would prefer but this is what I had.